# How to recover from "No authentication methods configured" on login page

Tags: gitlab

While trying to get [GitLab Kanban Board](http://kanban.leanlabs.io/) to run nicely with my GitLab server I somehow managed to get myself locked out of the latter.  Whenever I open the GitLab-URL now there's the message "No authentication methods configured" and no option for logging in.

Unfortunately, I don't even remember the exact settings that I was messing around with at that time, because it was a while ago and it's only now that I found the time for dealing with this problem again.  IIRC one of the last things I did was to try and get OAuth working.  (And I *think* that I was changing some settings in the web interface last, not in the settings files.)

Unable to find a solution online, one of the things I tried was to do a backup and then restore that on a different server.  But the result is that I then get the same message on the new server also.

Does anyone have any idea on how to recover from this situation?  Is there any way for example to enable "normal" login again by changing settings in the database?

If it's not (easily) possible to recover the whole GitLab installation, is there some way to somehow at least extract the bug report data from it?  That's the data that I would be most unhappy to loose...

I'd really appreciate any help, because I'm completely at a loss right now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Rails console to reenable your sign-in.

```
sudo gitlab-rails console
s = ApplicationSetting.find_by(signin_enabled: false)
s.signin_enabled = true
s.save
```

This will modify the rails settings directly.

Answer (score 1):

As of version **10.5.X**, use this instead (different `ApplicationSetting` key)

```
sudo gitlab-rails console
s = ApplicationSetting.find_by(password_authentication_enabled_for_web: false)
s.password_authentication_enabled_for_web = true
s.save
```

Comment: You saved the day. Thanks!